# Tikz: labels above the arrows using chains library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I'm using chains library from TikZ.
I would like to have a label(node?) above arrows. Is it possible?

I found [this](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/pgf-tikz-commutative-diagram/), but it is quite hackish.
Is there a standardized way?

Answer (score 3):

The page you link to isn't hackish. It's as simple and clean as it could be.

```
\chainin (m-2-3) [join={node[above] {$x$}}];
```

How much more straight forward could it get?

Comment: "a workaround by modifying the join method of the chain library. Its syntax is join=with<node> by <options>, I’m changing the syntax to join={node[options] {label}}" - I understand that old syntax won't work anymore?

Answer (score 3):

I also needed labeled edges for TikZ chains, but needed to retain the features of the original `join=with <node> by <options>` syntax.  So, I wrote some code to admit the syntax `join=with <node> by <options> nodes <node path>`.  Here is that code, along with an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\makeatletter

\def\tikz@lib@parse@join#1{%
  \def\tikz@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\tikz@temp\pgfutil@empty%
    \tikz@lib@join@by@nodes by {} nodes \pgfutil@stop%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@in@{nodes }{#1}%
    \ifpgfutil@in@%
      \tikz@lib@parse@join@nodes#1\pgfutil@stop%
    \else%
      \tikz@lib@parse@join@nodes#1 nodes \pgfutil@stop%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@nodes#1nodes #2\pgfutil@stop{%
  \pgfutil@in@{by }{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tikz@lib@parse@join@by#1nodes #2\pgfutil@stop%
  \else%
    \tikz@lib@parse@join@by#1by {} nodes #2\pgfutil@stop%
  \fi%
}

\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@by#1by #2 nodes #3\pgfutil@stop{%
  \pgfutil@in@{with }{#1}%
  \ifpgfutil@in@%
    \tikz@lib@join@with@by@nodes#1by #2 nodes #3\pgfutil@stop%
  \else%
    \tikz@lib@join@by@nodes by #2 nodes #3\pgfutil@stop%
  \fi%
}

\def\tikz@lib@join@with@by@nodes with #1 by #2 nodes #3\pgfutil@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={(#1)edge[every join,#2]#3(\tikzchaincurrent)}}%
}

\def\tikz@lib@join@by@nodes by #1 nodes #2\pgfutil@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={%
             \ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty%
             \else%
               (\tikzchainprevious)edge[every join,#1]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)%
             \fi}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, every join/.append style={->}]
  \node [on chain, join] {A};

  \node [on chain, join] {B};

  \node [on chain, join=nodes {node [above] {$\gamma$}}] {C};

  \node [on chain=going below,
         join=by {red}  nodes {node [right] {$\delta$}}] {D};

  \node [continue chain=going left, on chain,
         join,
         join=with chain-begin by {<-, blue}
              nodes {node [sloped,above] {$\epsilon$}},
         join=with chain-2 by {|->, red}] {E};

  \node [on chain, join=by {<->,green},
                   join=with chain-begin] {F};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Explanation

### `\tikz@lib@parse@join` Macro

1. `\tikz@lib@parse@join` first checks whether the argument to `join` is empty.  If so, the join occurs with empty `by` and `nodes` components and *no* `with` component.
2. Otherwise, we check whether there is a `nodes` component.  If not, we append an empty `nodes` component to `#1`; the space inserted between `#1` and `nodes` is needed because `#1` (is *not* empty and) does not end with a space.  We then call `\tikz@lib@parse@join@nodes`.

### `\tikz@lib@parse@join@nodes` Macro

Now, thanks to the previous macro, a (possibly empty) `nodes` component is guaranteed to exist.  We next check whether there is a `by` component.  If not, we insert an empty `by` component.  We then call `\tikz@lib@parse@join@by`.

Note that, in case we must insert an empty `by`, we do *not* add a space between `#1` and `by`.  This is because either:

- there was only a `nodes` component, in which case `#1` is empty; or
- there was a `with` component in addition to the `nodes` component, in which case `#1` contains the `with` and itself ends with a space.

### `\tikz@lib@parse@join@by` Macro

Now, thanks to the previous macros, (possibly empty) `by` and `nodes` components are guaranteed to exist.  We next check whether there is a `with` component.  If so, we call `\tikz@lib@join@with@by@nodes`.  Otherwise, we call `\tikz@lib@join@by@nodes`.

Comment: I tried to use `join=by {to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}} nodes {node[above]{a}` but that did not work? Maybe you know why?

Answer (score 0):

`edge node=node {node content}` is one solution. Here is a template that I use to draw state machines:

```tex
\usetikzlibrary {automata, chains}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,
    state/.style={state with output, on chain},
    start chain,
    on grid,
    node distance=2cm,
    auto,
]
\node[state] {a};
\node[
    state,
    join=by {
        edge node=node {1},
        ->,
        bend left
    },
] {b \nodepart{lower} $OK$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Alternatively the fancy `quotes` syntax:

```tex
\usetikzlibrary {automata, chains, quotes}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    shorten >=1pt,
    state/.style={state with output, on chain},
    start chain,
    on grid,
    node distance=2cm,
    auto,
]
\node[state] {a};
\node[
    state,
    join=by {
        "1",
        ->,
        bend left
    },
] {b \nodepart{lower} $OK$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```